# Como pasar un parametro a un metodo en el State en Flutter

Tags: flutter, http, params

soy novato en Flutter y estoy trabajando en mi primera App.

Tengo Dos pantallas, la primera es un Login y la Segunda una pantalla de Home(Bienvenida).

Envío un parametro de mi pantalla del Login al home, posteriormente hago una petición Http a mi mackend para obtener la informacion del usuario por medio del email.

El problema es que cuando llamo al metodo getUser() que se encuentra en el State no me es posible enviar el correo que previamente recibí como parámetro.

Mi código es el siguiente, si alguien me puede decir como enviarlo, ya intenté
como widget.email y me aparece el error _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

HomePage

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:login/services/services.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class HomePages extends StatefulWidget {

  final String email;

  const HomePages({
    required this.email,
    Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: no_logic_in_create_state
  _HomePagesState createState() => _HomePagesState();

}

class _HomePagesState extends State<HomePages> {

  String email = '';

  String _name = '';

  _HomePagesState(){


    //Aqui necesito enviar el email
    getUser('').then((value) => setState(() {

      _name = value;

      print(_name);
    }));


  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(''),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            DrawerHeader(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue
              ), child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const Text('Bienvenido:', style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 14
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    _name, style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.home),
              title: Text('Inicio'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.login_rounded),
              title: const Text('Cerrar sesión'),
              onTap: (){
                authService.logout();
                Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'login');
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<String> getUser(String email) async{


    //aqui necesito recibir el EMAIL para concatenarlo al url
    var url = Uri.https('restserver-smapac.herokuapp.com', '/api/usuarios/email/'+email); 

    var resp = await http.get(Uri.parse(url.toString()));

    if(resp.statusCode == 200){

      var jsonResponse = json.decode(resp.body);

      print(jsonResponse['nombre']);

      return jsonResponse['nombre'];

    }else{
      return 'no name';
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Creo que tu problema es que intentas acceder a email en tu HomePageState y tienes una variable que defines ahí, y mas bien deberías acceder a la variable email que recibes en tu StateFullwidget  asi  `widget.email`. `getUser(widget.email)`

Comment: No sé si termino de entender lo que estás haciendo... Pero no debes usar el constructor de un State. Si necesitas hacer alguna operación cuando el widget se está inicializando, usa el método initState. Por otro lado, si tienes una pantalla de login, ¿por qué no recuperas el nombre en ella y se lo pasas directamente al home, en lugar de llamar al backend en el home? Eso no tiene sentido, a mi parecer.

Comment: Es cierto lo que dice Manuel, deberias llamar al método getUser en la página de login, para que luego puedas guardar como variable de usuario o bien pasarla como parámetro a tu HomePage, supongo que el usuario se logea por medio del Email, ahí podrías llamar al método

Comment: creo que tu enfoque esta mal desde el inicio. Desde mi punto de vista, en la pantalla de Login debes realizar todo el proceso lógico para loguear o rechazar al usuario, en esa misma pantalla obtienes los datos del usuario logueado (email, nombres, etc.) y esos datos los pasas como parámetros limpios a la pantalla de inicio, o puedes usar un manejador de estado (Provider, Bloc, Getx, etc) y cargarlos allí para que esten disponibles en tu árbol de widgets.